# Form Submit after Ajax Callback

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to submit the form #mc-embedded-subscribe-form after ajax success function but it seems not to be working. When I alert "OK" after the function success it works fine but when I try to fire de submit function it does not. Thanks!

```
<form action="//google.us12.mailchimp.com/subscribe/" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>

<input type="email" id="mce-EMAIL" name="EMAIL" value="" placeholder="Email..."/>

</form>
<div class="email_submit" id="btn_email" style="">Subscribe</div>
```

AJAX

```
$("#btn_email").click(function() {

$('#btn_email').hide();
$('#btn_email_load').show();

var email = $('#mce-EMAIL').val();

$.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "classes/_mailchimp.php",
        data:{ email: email, },

        cache: false,

        success:function(data){

        if(data == 'ok'){ 

        $("form#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").submit();
        //alert("OK")

        return false;
        }

        alert(data);
        return false;
}
});
```

Comment: is the response defo 'ok'

Comment: are you getting an error or just no action?

Comment: run an else on the if(data == 'ok'){} else { alert('data is not ok'); }

Comment: Is there any default action on button click?

Comment: Just no action. When I alert "OK" it works fine. Thanks @Raif

Comment: No default action. It only fires this function. Thanks @markoffden

Comment: Any handlers for `#mc-embedded-subscribe-form` submit?

Comment: Default action should be keypress I think. Thanks @u_mulder

Comment: try to cash forms jQuery object like var formToSubmit = $('#your-form'), then   formToSubmit.submit()

Comment: Inside of your success function, I would interrogate the $("form#blah") result.  i.e. cast it to a variable and see what you actually have there before calling submit.

Comment: can you do a `console.log(data)` before you submit and tell us what is getting logged?

Comment: or .trigger('submit'), it may seem like random 'roll-of-the-dice' JS coding, but I do not see clear, why your code is not working

Comment: It doesn't work. Thanks @markoffden

Comment: @markoffden : may be it is working correctly but the OP confused as to why the desired behavior is not observed. :)

Comment: nothing yet. How do I alert console.log(data) Thanks @AdityaParab

Comment: you just do an alert, or a console.log.  or is your question that it's just showing [object:object]? if so, you can JSON.stringify(data) and put that in your log.  Or you can debug in your browser, put a break point on the line and inspect in the dev tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this question using 'async: false,' into the AJAX call. Thanks.

```
$.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "classes/_mailchimp.php",
        data:{ email: email, },
        async: false, //solution
        cache: false,

        success:function(data){

        if(data == 'ok'){ 

        $("form#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").submit();
        //alert("OK")

        return false;
        }

        alert(data);
        return false;
}
});
```

Comment: `async: false` is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

Well. First try to remove your method and action attributtes in the form because are not neccesary if you are using ajax already.

1. Rewrite the form attributes and put a real input button like:

   ```
   <form id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate">
   <!--We remove too the value attribute because is innecessary-->
   <input type="email" id="mce-EMAIL" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Email..."/>

   <input type="button" class="email_submit" id="btn_email" value="Suscribe"> </form>

       <!--We are creating another div that it will show when #btn_email has been listened-->  <div id="#btn_email_load" style="display:none">
   ```
2. Please watch that I'm putting the button within the form and not out there. So, the next is your ajax code. Changes and erros are commented

   ```
   $("#btn_email").click(function() {

       $('#btn_email').hide();
       $('#btn_email_load').show();

       var email = $('#mce-EMAIL').val();
       $values = 'mail='+email;
           $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "classes/_mailchimp.php",
                   //Save all the data in a variable and not an object, if you want to save it with an object, use the short .post() ajax method to do it. In this case, we gonna save the data in a variable before declared as $values
                   data:$values,
                   cache: false,

                   success:function(data){

                   if (data == 'ok'){ 
                       alert('ok')
                   }
           }); //close your ajax petition
   });
   ```